# Ansible lineinfile adds new line before edit

Tags: ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to edit the value of existing line without overriding it, when I run the playbook it adds the value in a new line

```
Line: server=foo

Value I'm trying to add: boo
```

**Exception:**

```
Line: server=foo,boo
```

**Result:**

```
Line: server=foo,
boo
```

**Code:**

```
- name: Update
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ file_path }}"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '(server=.*)'
    line: '\1,boo'
```

Comment: If I try running your code it seems to do exactly what you want. See my complete test [here](https://asciinema.org/a/zHNFDzbM3Pa8ZoWygijgAgKaj).

Comment: This is really odd, could it be since I run in WSL?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, since I run on WSL I had to do dos2unix and after edits unix2dos
and no extra new line added

Comment: It's not really that you use WSL; it's just likely that you edited the playbook in a Windows editor that wrote DOS line-endings by default.  I highly recommend Visual Studio Code, since it has integration that will allow you to launch it and edit files directly from inside WSL.  Just install the "Remote Development" extension pack, then you can launch `code .` inside any Linux directory to open it in the editor.  Bonus - There are YAML extensions as well that will auto-format the playbook.

Comment: The real issue would be that the *destination file* has Windows line endings. The line endings in the playbook itself are irrelevant.

Comment: I'm using VC code and I have the extension you mention before posting about the issue